# show alternating rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have these tables:

```
    tblPerson

id | name |
 1 | A    |
 2 | B    |
 3 | C    |

    tblB
id | personId | loan |
 1 |      1   |  100 |
 2 |      1   |   50 |
 3 |      2   |   25 |

    tblC      
id | personId | payment |
 1 |      1   |      20 |
 2 |      1   |      10 |
```

How do I produce this output:

```
    Output
id | name | loan | payment | balance |
 1 |    A |  100 |       0 |     100 |
 1 |    A |    0 |      20 |      80 |
 1 |    A |   50 |       0 |     130 |
 1 |    A |    0 |      10 |     120 |
 2 |    B |   25 |       0 |      25 |
```

I need the output to sbow the loan first then the payment the loan again and so on.

Comment: Why would you want to interleave them?  Don't you have dates that properly specify the ordering?

Comment: That's the only given sir

Comment: @Gordon Linoff That are just sample tables that I created for that output, I just wanted to know how to produce that output 'coz I need it in a much wider query

Comment: It would seems your schema needs some work. IN addition to the comment by @GordonLinoff, you should also relate payments to the loan to which they relate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/759df4/3/0) will generate an interleaved set of loans and payments.

```
SELECT id,name,loan,payment
FROM (
SELECT p.id    id,
       p.name  name,
       0       type,
       b.id    detail_id,
       b.loan  loan,
       0       payment
  FROM person p
  JOIN b ON p.id = b.personId
 UNION ALL 
SELECT p.id      id,
       p.name    name,
       1         type,
       c.id      detail_id,
       0         loan,
       c.payment payment
  FROM person p
  JOIN c ON p.id = c.personId

) q
ORDER BY id, detail_id, type
```

Then, I suppose you can use variables to generate the running totals. But Dr. Linoff is right (see his comment) that the dataset you've shown doesn't have enough information reliably to interleave loan and payment records. I've used ID fields to do this.  The last `ORDER BY` really ought to mention `posting_date` or some other information instead of `detail_id`, if you have it elsewhere in your tables

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *, (sum(tb.loan) / sum(tc.payment)) as balance 
from tblPerson tp
join tblB tb on tp.id = tb.personId
join tblC tc on tp.id = tc.personId
```

this is what comes to my head.